# When tapping a UIButton that was created programmatically is it possible to push to a controller that is editable in interface builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

Created a UIButton programmatically but the page it needs to link to will need to be the root controller view of a UINavigationController.

This page would be easier to create in interface builder rather than in code. When the button in question is tapped it needs to segue to another controller/view that I can edit in interface builder.

Possible or impossible?

If possible how can I do this? I feel I'll run into this problem quite often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible:

Create the button:

```
    UIButton *bottonOne = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 15, 65, 12)];
```

The set it up with a title / image as you need. Once you have done that do this:

```
    [buttonOne addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonOnepressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then in the same class create a method called `buttonOnepressed`

```
    -(void)buttonOnePressed
{
    //preform the steps needed for your segue method and anything else you want to do when the        button has been tapped
}
```

**Edit**

After reading your comments - you want a button you've created in code, to perform a segue without manually invoking the segue (Writing code to actually show the new screen) and you want it to behave like it would if you did a drag and drop in IB. If that's the case - the short answer is simply, no. If you create a button in code, all its actions need to be done in code, too.

**Edit 2**

Try this:

In IB create a "generic" segue like this:

Ctrl-drag from the source view controller to the other view you want to do to when the button is tapped. You can use the view controller object at the bottom of the scene to do this.

Give the segue an identifier.

Then use [self performSegueWithIdentifier@"Your Identifier"]; in your button tapped method to perform the segue

Comment: I do this already but what I wanted to know is how I can use a controller created in interface builder. I would like to edit the view of the controller the button pushes to but in interface builder and not in code.

Comment: So when you button is tapped - you want a viewController you created in IB  to show up on screen? You want to do with without manually invoking a segue to push the view controller onto screen, correct?

Comment: So, you want that you will be able to add labels, buttons etc to your view controller from the view itself?

Comment: Basically if I done this all in IB I would drag from the UIButton to the navigationController. In this instance I can't as the UIButton is created in code. I'd like to achieve the same thing but because the UIButton is in code I can't just drag and connect. If I create a navigationController in IB and make another controller root controller of it they would both just sit there connected to nothing and I'd get a yellow warning message.

Comment: So there is no way it can push to controller that was created in IB? Main reason being the page I want to design would be easier to design visually rather than in code.

Comment: There is... in code. In my answer in the buttonOnePressed method - you can present a view controller via a few lines of code.

Comment: This is what I intended to do. Maybe I worded my description incorrectly. I've added a navigation controller and give it an storyboard ID. In the method connected to my button I've added a log message to check it's being triggered and then added this line:   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nameOfmyIdentifier" sender:sender];  however I get an error "has no segue with identifier 'refineGarment''"

Comment: Okay now we're getting somewhere. You cannot perform a segue you have not created. You cannot create a segue in code. I'll update my answer on how to do what you're asking..

Comment: Works great. Had to click on the segue connection symbol then name the identifier then user the [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueIdentifier" sender:sender]; method in the button method.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this :

Button creation:

```
 UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25)];
 [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Button method:

```
 - (void)btnMethod:(UIButton *)sender
 {
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueIdentifier" sender:sender]; 
 }
```